# Why is my Nvidia GPU Idle most of the time?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I am using NVIDIA Optimus GPU State Viewer and running an android emulator simultaneously and most of the time it shows the GPU state: **IDLE**,
however sometimes it blinks to **ON** for a few milliseconds ,

My question is , is that a normal behaviour and if it is , isn't it harmful to switch GPUs so rapidly in any way ?

One more thing to note is that i'm on a laptop so this behaviour is only seen when laptop is plugged in otherwise it (GPU state viewer) only shows GPU state: **OFF**

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDbpg.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a side effect of how NVIDIA Optimus actually works.

As a point of reference, the general sequence of events to render a single frame for a regular discrete GPU setup is as follows:

1. The CPU collects the data required to render the frame and sends it to the GPU.
2. The GPU renders the frame.
3. The GPU then sends the frame over the video output.

When using a discrete GPU with NVIDIA Optimus however, things are more complicated:

1. The CPU collects the data required to render the frame and sends it to the discrete GPU.
2. The discrete GPU renders the frame.
3. The rendered frame isthen sent to the integrated GPU (I don't know whether this is CPU mediated or done as a DMA transfer directly from one GPU to the other, but it doesn't matter for this discussion)
4. The integrated GPU then sends the frame over the video output.

This is done to avoid the need for hardware multiplexing of the video output (which was the main source of limitations in first-generation hybrid GPU setups), and is also the main reason that NVIDIA Optimus (and AMD Hybrid Graphics) setups display slightly worse performance than just using an otherwise identical GPU.

However, it's actually a bit more complicated than that, because which GPU gets used to render the frame is determined *per application*. This means that when you have multiple applications open, different parts of the frame may be rendered by different GPUs before being composited into the final frame by the integrated GPU.

Because of this, the discrete GPU will only be utilized when there is actually an application running that needs to use it and that application is updating it's state on screen. Your Android emulator is almost certainly making Direct X or DXVA calls that will cause Optimus to use the discrete GPU for it (this is determined at application startup, not on the fly while the application is being run), but because it's an emulator it's probably only making calls to the host system to update what it is displaying when the contents of the emulated display have indeed changed, so it's not constantly using the GPU on the host.